# htaccess redirect does not work - redirects to wrong page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3, typo3-8.x

Hi I have to set some 301 redirects for an old page.

The old url is:

```
http://www.domain.de/de/haus.php?Lieblingsplatz
```

The new URL is:

```
https://domain.de/haus/maerchenhaeuser/
```

So I thought is not a big deal ... and tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^haus.php?Lieblingsplatz /haus/maerchenhaeuser/ [R=301,L]
```

Thats the way I do it normally ...

But result is in this case:

```
https://domain.de/firstpageURL/?Lieblingsplatz=
```

Whats wrong? ...

It's a regular TYPO3 v8 page with realURL.

Here is the full .htaccess.

```
#####
#
# Example .htaccess file for TYPO3 CMS - for use with Apache Webserver
#
# This file includes settings for the following configuration options:
#
# - Compression
# - Caching
# - MIME types
# - Cross Origin requests
# - Rewriting and Access
# - Miscellaneous
# - PHP optimisation
#
# If you want to use it, you have to copy it to the root folder of your TYPO3 installation (if its
# not there already) and rename it to '.htaccess'. To make .htaccess files work, you might need to
# adjust the 'AllowOverride' directive in your Apache configuration file.
#
# IMPORTANT: You may need to change this file depending on your TYPO3 installation!
#            Consider adding this file's content to your webserver's configuration directly for speed improvement
#
# Lots of the options are taken from https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess
#
####


### Begin: Compression ###

# Compressing resource files will save bandwidth and so improve loading speed especially for users
# with slower internet connections. TYPO3 can compress the .js and .css files for you.
# *) Uncomment the following lines and
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 for the Backend
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 together with the TypoScript properties
#    config.compressJs and config.compressCss for GZIP compression of Frontend JS and CSS files.

#<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/css" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#AddEncoding gzip .gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    #
    # (!) For Apache versions below version 2.3.7 you don't need to
    # enable `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`
    # and `</IfModule>` lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in
    # the core directives.
    #
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
            application/javascript \
            application/json \
            application/ld+json \
            application/manifest+json \
            application/rdf+xml \
            application/rss+xml \
            application/schema+json \
            application/vnd.geo+json \
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
            application/x-font-ttf \
            application/x-javascript \
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
            application/xhtml+xml \
            application/xml \
            font/eot \
            font/opentype \
            image/bmp \
            image/svg+xml \
            image/vnd.microsoft.icon \
            image/x-icon \
            text/cache-manifest \
            text/css \
            text/html \
            text/javascript \
            text/plain \
            text/vcard \
            text/vnd.rim.location.xloc \
            text/vtt \
            text/x-component \
            text/x-cross-domain-policy \
            text/xml
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

### End: Compression ###



### Begin: Browser caching of resource files ###

# This affects Frontend and Backend and increases performance.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>

### End: Browser caching of resource files ###


### Begin: MIME types ###

# Proper MIME types for all files
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    # Data interchange
    AddType application/atom+xml                        atom
    AddType application/json                            json map topojson
    AddType application/ld+json                         jsonld
    AddType application/rss+xml                         rss
    AddType application/vnd.geo+json                    geojson
    AddType application/xml                             rdf xml

    # JavaScript
    AddType application/javascript                      js

    # Manifest files
    AddType application/manifest+json                   webmanifest
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache

    # Media files

    AddType audio/mp4                                   f4a f4b m4a
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg opus
    AddType image/bmp                                   bmp
    AddType image/svg+xml                               svg svgz
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType video/mp4                                   f4v f4p m4v mp4
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv
    AddType image/x-icon                                cur ico

    # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/font-woff2                      woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf

    # Other
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-bb-appworld                   bbaw
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType text/vcard                                  vcard vcf
    AddType text/vnd.rim.location.xloc                  xloc
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc

</IfModule>

# UTF-8 encoding
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .manifest .rdf .rss .vtt .webapp .webmanifest .xml
</IfModule>

### End: MIME types ###



### Begin: Cross Origin ###

# Send the CORS header for images when browsers request it.
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Allow cross-origin access to web fonts.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

### End: Cross Origin ###



### Begin: Rewriting and Access ###

# You need rewriting, if you use a URL-Rewriting extension (RealURL, CoolUri).

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Enable URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # Store the current location in an environment variable CWD to use
    # mod_rewrite in .htaccess files without knowing the RewriteBase
    RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]

    # Rules to set ApplicationContext based on hostname
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production/Staging]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production]

    # Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ %{ENV:CWD}$1.$3 [L]

    # Access block for folders
    RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]
    RewriteRule fileadmin/templates/.*\.(?:txt|ts)$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^(?:vendor|typo3_src|typo3temp/var) - [F]
    RewriteRule (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?|Documentation|docs?)/ - [F]

    # Block access to all hidden files and directories with the exception of
    # the visible content from within the `/.well-known/` hidden directory (RFC 5785).
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule (?:^|/)\. - [F]

    # Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
    # NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
    RewriteRule ^(?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

    # If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
    # For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# Access block for files
<FilesMatch "(?i:^\.|^#.*#|^(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|^composer\.(?:json|lock)|^ext_conf_template\.txt|^ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|^ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*)|.*(?:~|rc))$">
    # Apache < 2.3
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </IfModule>

    # Apache ≥ 2.3
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Block access to vcs directories
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 404 /\.(?:git|svn|hg)/
</IfModule>

### End: Rewriting and Access ###



### Begin: Miscellaneous ###

# 404 error prevention for non-existing redirected folders
Options -MultiViews

# Make sure that directory listings are disabled.
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Force IE to render pages in the highest available mode
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svgz?|ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff2?|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

    # Reducing MIME type security risks
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

# ETag removal
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None

### End: Miscellaneous ###

RewriteRule ^haus.php?Lieblingsplatz /haus/maerchenhaeuser/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: also tried this: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=Lieblingsplatz
 RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.de/haus/maerchenhaeuser/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Is there a `key` parameter in your URL `http://www.domain.de/de/haus.php?Lieblingsplatz` ?

Comment: no there is no key parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your problem is not related to TYPO3, it's pure mod_rewrite.

Second: you should place your own rewrite rules right after `RewriteEngine On`. Otherwise your rules might not get evaluated because other rules kick in first.

To fix your problem, please try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Lieblingsplatz
RewriteRule ^haus.php /haus/maerchenhaeuser/? [R=301,L]
```

`RewriteCond` checks if the query string consists of `Lieblingsplatz`.
The quotation mark at the end of the redirect target removes the existing query string `?Lieblingsplatz`. Otherwise you might end up in an endless redirect loop.

To make things easier you might waive the test for `^haus.php` and test only for query string. In this case, the second line should look like this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /haus/maerchenhaeuser/? [R=301,L]`